# Converting hexadecimal to decimal number in c

Tags: c, numbers, hex

I was implementing a program to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal in C but my program is not working. Please help me to get the program working.

I dont know which part of the program has bug. Any suggestion and answers will be helpful.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

char hexNum[100];
int getDecimal();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Enter the hex number: ");
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        hexNum[i++] = ch;
    }
    hexNum[i] = '\0';
    printf("\nHexadecimal Number is: %s", hexNum);
    int n = getDecimal();
    printf("\nDecimal Number is: " + n);
    return 0;
}

int getDecimal() {
    //get to the units digit index
    int index = 0;
    while (hexNum[index + 1] != '\0') {
        index++;
    }
    //calculate the decimal value and store the result in result var
    int var = 0;  //store the decimal number
    int exp = 0;  //keep track of exponent of 16^x
    while (index >= 0) {
        int ch = hexNum[index--];
        switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
            var = var + (10 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        case 'b':
            var = var + (11 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        case 'c':
            var = var + (12 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        case 'd':
            var = var + (13 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        case 'e':
            var = var + (14 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        case 'f':
            var = var + (15 * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        default:   //if its a digit
            var = var + ((ch-'0') * pow(16, exp++));
            break;
        }
    }
    return var;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small program (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Once you do the legwork to pinpoint to the bug, if the cause is unclear to you, then by all means ask a question. As it is now, your question is a bad fit for SO, since it's nothing more than a debugging request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
    printf("\nDecimal Number is: " + n);
```

to

```
    printf("\nDecimal Number is: %d\n", n);
```

Besides that your algorithm is too complicated and performance is poor.

It is better to use forward iteration instead of backward. Something like:

```
var = 0;
index = 0;
while (hexNum[index]  != '\0')
{
    var = 16 * var;

    switch (hexNum[index]) {
    case 'a':
        var = var + 10;
        break;
    case 'b':
        var = var + 11;
        break;
    ... and so on ...
    }
    ++index;
}
return var;
```

Comment: I have changed the soln but its showing runtime error.(https://ideone.com/Epmupb). Can you please fix it and give me the link ?

Comment: @MarcoRoberts `var=var+('0'-hexNum[index]);` -> `var=var+(hexNum[index] - '0');` And you did **not** change the printf statement. Try that first and let me know if you still have problems

Comment: @MarcoRoberts - also remember to press newline in the stdin. If you don't the program will run forever. An ideone it will crash after so time....

Answer (score 0):

For e.g. '12' you compute  1 * pow(16,0) + 2 * pow(16,1) which is probably
not what you want, except if you want to enter the number in *reverse* order ...

Comment: 12 will compute to=> 2*pow(16,0)+1*pow(16,1) because my var `index` initially point to last element of `hexNum` using condition `while (hexNum[index + 1] != '\0')  index++;`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ValidationNumber(char *value)
{
    char *ptr=NULL;
    if(isdigit(*value)){
        ptr=valor;
        ///ptr=(int*) value;
        }
    return ptr;
}

char *ptr,c;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    printf("Enter number: %i ");
    scanf("%i");
    ptr=&c;
    if(ValidatioNumber(ptr) !=NULL){
        printf("Valid value: %i");
    }else
        printf("Input invalid");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```